# XcodeGen how to specify SPM Package

Tags: ios, xcode, dependency-management, swift-package-manager, xcodegen

I’m using [XcodeGen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/) for my project and curious how to add specific package from SPM?

Refer to screenshot, this is how I'm doing manually:
[image]

This is my config for packages:

```
packages:
  Charts:
    url: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts
    branch: master
```

Observing of [documentation](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/blob/master/Docs/ProjectSpec.md#swift-package) I don’t see anything about that.
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the product you need when you define the dependencies:

```
dependencies:
    - package: Charts
      product: Charts
```

<sub>Search for **Package dependency** in the [documentation](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/blob/master/Docs/ProjectSpec.md)</sub>

Comment: Thanks that’s what I missed